# Cannot duplicate table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to duplicate a table using phpmyadmin. It generates the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `agendaeventos`.`diassemamaactivo` (

`idEvento` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `idExterno` VARCHAR( 16 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `nombreEvento` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL ,
 `entradilla` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
 `descripcion` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
 `diaDeInicio` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `diaDeFin` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `diaDeInicioYFinTexto` VARCHAR( 58 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `horarioTexto` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
 `fotoURL` VARCHAR( 200 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `webURL` VARCHAR( 200 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `idFuente` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `esRevisado` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `esModificado` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `fechaActualizacion` DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
 `diasSemanaActivo` CHAR( 7 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT  '1111111',
PRIMARY KEY (  `idEvento` )
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 372DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
```

But it returns the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '372DEFAULT CHARSET  = utf8 COLLATE  = utf8_unicode_ci' at line 17
```

I can't see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

separate like this

```
372 DEFAULT
```

copy or edit the query , correct  and reexecute

Comment: Thanks, I was confused by a error mark phpmyadmin placed in the query pointing to another line. In fact it was not trying to mark any line but the whole query.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space in 372DEFAULT